# Android camera write text directly into frame

Tags: android, camera, frame

I have camera (the "deprecated" API) and camera PreviewCallback, in which I get frames. I use that to take pictures (not takePicure or PictureCallback, because I want it fast over quality) and save as jpeg, code snippset below:

```
@Override
public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera camera) {
    YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(frame, previewFormat, width, height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);
    out.toByteArray(); // this is my JPEG
    // ... save this JPEG
}
```

I want to draw text, timestamp, into frame. I know how to do this by converting to Bitmap, using Canvas, drawing text and converting to Bitmap again. But this method is relatively slow (it's not biggest issue), but also i need the frame byte array to other things i.e. put into video and I would like to know if there is some method or lib to directly write text into that frame. I don't use preview (or rather, I use dummy preview), I'm asking how to change the frame byte array. I bet I'd need to do some mumble-jumble into byte array to make it work. The frame is in standard(?) format (YUV420/NV21).

Edit:
I managed to get a working function (getNV21). Of course it is far from efficient at it creates new Bitmap every frame and draws text to it but at least i have something I can work on, directly into yuv image. Still, answers would be appreciated.

```
private Bitmap drawText(String text, int rotation) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(height/36);
    paint.setTextSize(height/36);
    paint.setShadowLayer(5f, 0f, 0f, Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

    if (rotation == 0 || rotation == 180) {
        canvas.rotate(rotation,width/2,height/2);
    } else {
        canvas.translate(Math.abs(width-height), 0);
        int w = width/2 - Math.abs(width/2-height/2);
        int h = height/2;
        canvas.rotate(-rotation,w,h);
    }
    canvas.drawText(text, 10, height-10, paint);

    return bitmap;
}

byte [] getNV21(byte[] yuv, int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {

    int [] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

    scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

    encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

    scaled.recycle();

    return yuv;
}

private static void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    int yIndex = 0;
    int uvIndex = frameSize;

    int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++,index++,yIndex++) {

            a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
            R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

            if (R == 0 && G == 0 && B == 0) {
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) uvIndex+=2;
                continue;
            }

            // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
            Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
            U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
            //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
            //    pixel AND every other scanline.
            yuv420sp[yIndex] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
            if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) { 
                yuv420sp[uvIndex] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                yuv420sp[uvIndex] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
            }
        }
    }
}
```